# Backbone underscore update ui from model changes

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I using backbone with underscore. I have a button
    <%= model.testButtonText %>

This button is rendered in the render function of my view using template.

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically update the button's text when the model.testButtonText changes?

Or do I have to handle it specifically by binding to the model.testButtonText change and then do some jquery to find the element and update the text that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to bind every element to model change event you can use this plugin: http://rivetsjs.com

Natively Backbone doesn't support ui-bindings.

Comment: More plugins in the [View section here](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's tied to the `model` itself, you can listen for changes in your view to re-render it.

```
view.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

A useful extension for re-creating the view when your `model` changes -- [Backbone.ModelBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder).